# Org babel with noweb syntax and untangling

Tags: org-babel

I just stumbled upon the possibility of using noweb syntax with
org-babel, so that named source blocks can be referred to from
other blocks, as in

```
    #+name: hullo
    #+begin_src 
    hullo there,
    #+end_src

    #+begin_src 
    <<hullo>>
    world
    #+end_src
```

As great as my initial delight, so also was my disappointment as
I learned that this does not seem to work well with
`org-babel-detangle`.  So just to make sure: there's no existing
way to make noweb syntax and untangling work together, is there?

Comment: No: the detangling assumes that the tangled blocks are distinct (no overlap at all), whereas noweb produces nested tangled blocks. It would be relatively easy (I think, without having tried it) to get back to the correct block (basically, when looking back for the proper link, skip any nested links that do not match the end tag). But propagating back any changes will require some additional finesse, which may or may not be easy.

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't implemented, as `org-babel-tangle-jump-to-org` does work